# "Object pronoun + all" = ? = "all + of + Object pronoun"

Tags: meaning, usage

I was wondering if the following sentences mean exactly the same:

> **1a.** She’s invited **all of you**. 
> **1b.** She’s invited **you all**.
>
> **2a.** Lucy sent her love to **all of you**. 
> **2b.** Lucy sent her love to **you all**.
>
> **3a.** **They all** went at home. 
> **3b.** **All of them** went at home.

Actually I doubt weather using 'you all' instead of 'all of you' which sounds more natural in standard English, is a less preferable choice or they do not make any difference in both formal and colloquial English at all.

Ps. having into consideration that in number 3 we have a subject pronoun.

Comment: All are natural. All mean the same.

Comment: But not "at home". Just home.  They all went home. What you've said is that they all emptied their bladders at home. :-)

Comment: Sorry @TRomano and Thanks for the prompt reply. I know that. It was just a typo. You are absolutely right. ;)

Answer (score 1):

"You all" is usually shortened to "y'all".  Yes, it means "all of you".  It is used in the Southern dialect of American English as "the plural of you", when conjugating verbs.

For example, in Standard English:

> I do.  We do.
>
> You do.  You do.
>
> He does.  They do.

And in the Southern dialect of American English:

> I do.  We do.
>
> You do.  Y'all do.
>
> "He does" or "He do".  They do.

"Y'all" is not Standard English.  In practice, this means that "y'all" is informal, and that most uses of "you all" are informal.  Using "you all" at the end of a sentence is informal, such as in the original poster's examples.

"You all" can be used formally, but only in certain ways.  For example:

> "You all went home after the party, so I cleaned up by myself."